# Problema básico POD y Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para poder aprender Kubernetes, creo que el mismo está un poco desactualizado, en el tutorial hacemos un ejemplo sencillo de nuestro primer POD:

```
kubectl run --image=nginx:alpine podtest
```

Posterior a esto copiamos la IP del POD mediante:

```
kubectl describe pod podtest
```

En mi caso la IP es

> 172.17.0.3

En el curso que estoy siguiendo usan esta IP para acceder a la página de bienvenida de nginx, pero en mi caso esta IP no me regresa absolutamente nada.

Estuve intentando de todo, pero no logro acceder a la página de inicio de nginx

Answer (score 1):

No puedes porque tu IP no está en la red de kubernetes.

Necesitas crear un servicio.

```
$ kubectl expose pod podtest --port=8080 --type=NodePort

$ kubectl get svc
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          127m
podtest      NodePort    10.96.128.241   <none>        8080:31344/TCP   27s
```

A mi me aparece el puerto en `31344` para el host local.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto y vuelve a intentar acceder con la IP de tu host

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: podtest
spec:
  hostNetwork: true
  containers:
  - name: podtest
    image: nginx
```

Comment: Las respuestas que son solo código son consideradas de baja calidad, por favor edita tu respuesta y agrega cómo esto soluciona el problema de OP y mucho mejor si puedes agregar enlaces de documentación para que tu respuesta sea más completa. ;)